# Steamworks - Set AppID

Tags: c#

I'm currently using the [Steamworks.NET](https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET) library from *[rlabrecque](https://github.com/rlabrecque)*. And there was a problem with her work. Maybe someone came across this, but I want to get rid of the steam_appid.txt file next to my *.exe application. If it is simply deleted, the library issues "Steamworks in not initialized".
Please advise how to programmatically install Appid, without using the file steam_appid.txt next to my *.exe ?!

P.S. I tried

```
SteamAPI.Init();
new AppId_t(252490);
```

but it did not help :(

P.P.S. Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: If you have a look at the [native Steamworks API SteamAPI_Init](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/steam_api) you can see that the file is unnecessary if you launch your game through Steam client, it's for debugging purposes only. Are you running Steam client on your machine?

Comment: @orhtej2, Of course. The program starts when the game is already open. But all the same he knocks out the error that "Steamworks is not initialized".
(the game is launched from the official Steam, the game bought from Steam is also officially).